# JsViews Data-Link Helper Function

Tags: jsviews

I have the following helper defined:

```
$.views.helpers({
    total: function(lines) {
        var total = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            total += lines[i].price * lines[i].quantity;
        }

        return total;
    }
});
```

Then I have have the following code to data link my model to my view:

```
var model = {
    lines: []
};

$("#lines").link(true, model);
```

Finally within the view I have the following:

```
<span data-link="~total(lines)"></span>
```

However whenever I observably add or remove items from the array it doesn't update the total. I read that you could pass in lines.length into the function and indeed it updated the total each time I added or removed an item. But when I observably updated the quantity property against any of the lines the total did not update.

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you found with https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/280, there is not currently a declarative syntax for depending on "All". Probably after V1.0 that feature will be added - along the lines of `total.depends = "lines**";` or `total.depends = "lines*.*";` for a helper: `function total(...)`...

Meantime you can use a programmatic approach - which is still very easy. Just trigger a refresh by adding:

```
$.observable(model.lines).observeAll(function() {
    $("#lines").link(true, model);
})
```

or refresh just the 'total' span by writing:

```
<span id="total" data-link="~total(lines)"></span>
```

and

```
$.observable(model.lines).observeAll(function() {
    $("#total").link(true, model);
})
```

See for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/wch601L9/

Comment: Thanks Boris. I've been using it in production for a while and it's been very stable so I'm sure a v1 is not far off. I would only ask for one small suggestion. It would be nice if you could say $(selector).link(model) instead of passing in true. Looking at the code it should be just a case of checking if the first parameter is an object.

Comment: The syntax using $(selector).link(true, model ...) has the advantage of being clearly differentiated from $(selector).link(linkExpression, model ...). If there is a 'true', then it is activating the declarative data-link expressions. If not then it is binding a linkExpression programmatically. The effort of passing in that boolean is I think justified by the more 'self-documenting' nature of the API. The second parameter is always the model. The first is either a flag (true) for declarative binding, or an expression - for programmatic binding.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you have any examples of programmatic binding? I've only ever used declarative binding by passing in true.

Comment: I have some new documentation topics on declarative and programmatic top-level data linking - which will be part of the next update. Meantime, there are unit tests such as here:  https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/blob/master/test/unit-tests/tests-jsviews.js#L1096. See also this syntax: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews.com/blob/gh-pages/samples/tag-controls/tree/if-binding/sample.js#L40 which could have been written using template.link(selector, model) - but $(selector).link(template, model) is supported too.

Comment: Thanks. This helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following issue which has a couple of suggested fixes:

https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/280

Unfortunately both are abit of a hack but I guess it will have to do for now.